# How to access KVM windows guest bios

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

How to access KVM windows guest bios:

As I want to check guest bios virtuliazation options to enable nested virtuliazation, like vm inside vm.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM#Nested_virtualization

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is done via the "guest bios", to set up nested virtualization with KVM, there are specific guides per distribution, which you failed to mention.